# Как привязать анимацию к открытию/закрытию меню паузы на Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр, ui, unity3d-ui

Я создал аниматор с двумя анимациями для открытия и закрытия меню паузы в игре следующим образом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но когда я запускаю это меню, ни одна из анимаций не срабатывает. Я новичок в Unity UI, но предполагаю, что нужно вставить вызов из аниматора в скрипт. Я пробовал несколько способов, но постоянно выдавало разные ошибки. Мог бы кто-нибудь помочь встроить вызов анимаций из скрипта правильным образом? Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Вот скрипт:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Pause_menu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static bool GameIsPaused = false;

    public GameObject pauseMenuUI;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            if (GameIsPaused)
                Resume();
            else
                Pause();
        }
    }

    public void Resume()
    {
        pauseMenuUI.SetActive(false);
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
        GameIsPaused = false;
        
    }

    void Pause()
    {
        pauseMenuUI.SetActive(true);
        Time.timeScale = 0f;
        GameIsPaused = true;
    }
}
```